# Parsing section from XML

Tags: java, dom, html-parsing

I have a XML document. From the whole document I want to parse a particular section using Java

```
   <sec sec-type="methods">
    .....
   </sec>
```

There are child `sec` in the "methods". How do I parse it? I need to get the titles and the text content from each of the nodes.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by 'web link'. What programming language are you proposing to work in?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to parse the entire document, not just a section of the document.  Trying to pull a section out of an XML document without parsing (at least) the stuff preceding it is liable to be fragile ... especially if there are changes in the way that the XML is created.

Second, you need to read up on the technologies for parsing XML and decide which one best suits your use-case.  Here are some resources:

- The [Sun XML Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html) stream.
- Wikipedia material on [XML processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Programming_interfaces) and [JAXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing).

There are various other approaches, but I don't want to confuse you with a million choices.